# Graphviz / DOT Language: Label causes error

Tags: plot, tree, graphviz, dot

When removing the label for `n30` it compiles although there are other nodes like `n5` which have the same label:

```
graph ""
{
n1 [label="CompilationUnit"] ;
n1 ;
n2 [label="None"] ;
n1 -- n2 ;
n3 [label="ClassDeclaration"] ;
n1 -- n3 ;
n3 -- n4 ;
n5 [label="None"] ;
n3 -- n5 ;
n6 [label="A"] ;
n3 -- n6 ;
n7 [label="FieldDeclaration"] ;
n3 -- n7 ;
n8 [label="None"] ;
n7 -- n8 ;
n7 -- n9 ;
n10 [label="BasicType"] ;
n7 -- n10 ;
n11 [label="int"] ;
n10 -- n11 ;
n12 [label="VariableDeclarator"] ;
n7 -- n12 ;
n13 [label="a"] ;
n12 -- n13 ;
n14 [label="Literal"] ;
n12 -- n14 ;
n15 [label="None"] ;
n14 -- n15 ;
n16 [label="5"] ;
n14 -- n16 ;
n17 [label="FieldDeclaration"] ;
n3 -- n17 ;
n18 [label="None"] ;
n17 -- n18 ;
n17 -- n19 ;
n20 [label="BasicType"] ;
n17 -- n20 ;
n21 [label="int"] ;
n20 -- n21 ;
n22 [label="VariableDeclarator"] ;
n17 -- n22 ;
n23 [label="b"] ;
n22 -- n23 ;
n24 [label="BinaryOperation"] ;
n22 -- n24 ;
n24 -- n25 ;
n26 [label="Literal"] ;
n24 -- n26 ;
n27 [label="None"] ;
n26 -- n27 ;
n28 [label="6"] ;
n26 -- n28 ;
n29 [label="Literal"] ;
n24 -- n29 ;
n30 [label="None"] ;
n29 -- n30 ;
n29 -- n31 ;
n3 -- n32 ;
n32 -- n33 ;
n32 -- n34 ;
n32 -- n35 ;
n35 -- n36 ;
n32 -- n37 ;
n37 -- n38 ;
n37 -- n39 ;
n39 -- n40 ;
n39 -- n41 ;
n3 -- n42 ;
n3 -- n43 ;
n3 -- n44 ;
n1 -- n45 ;
n45 -- n46 ;
n45 -- n47 ;
n45 -- n48 ;
n45 -- n49 ;
n45 -- n50 ;
n45 -- n51 ;
}
```

I have used [this page](http://sandbox.kidstrythisathome.com/erdos/) to generate the plot. As in the comments mentioned it does work on [viz-js.com](http://viz-js.com), at least for svg, but **not for png image**. Seems really weird.

Comment: Works here http://viz-js.com/

Comment: @marapet: Interesting, thanks, but it doesn't work for png-image-element. Then there is an error as well.

Comment: Works fine here, in Graphviz 2.38.0.  Perhaps you had some oddball invisible character in that line (a non-breaking space, or similar), that got eliminated when pasting the code here.

Comment: If I copy it from here and paste it in the page I mentioned or viz-js.com it's the same error. And there should be no different between that line and others since they are generated automatically in the same way. But good to know that it seems to work in the actual Graphiviz :)